# Where do I put my PHP files on Apache Solr?

Tags: php, solr, web-crawler

I am trying to create a front end for my web server (like text box to search for terms, and a search button).

- Where do I place these files?
- How do I access them from the browser?

I am using the [solr-php-client](https://github.com/PTCInc/solr-php-client) for creating [this](https://github.com/PTCInc/solr-php-client/wiki/Example-Usage) front end. However, I don't know where in my `solr-7.5.0` directoy to place these files.

Comment: You need to put your files inside the public directory of the server. It can be named `public` or `www` ,it will depend from your server configuration.

Comment: And how do I access that from the browser? `http://localhost:8983/` only takes me to a dashboard

Comment: What's the folder structure of your server? Have you tried by specifying the file name in your url like `http://localhost:8983/yourfilename.php`?

Comment: Tried that. No go. under solr-7.5.0 ->  solr-php-client/. I just cloned the repository in the main solr-7.5.0 folder. And in here, i created a test/index.php file. So I tried `http://localhost:8983/solr-php-client/test`. But it's not found

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to put the PHP files together with Solr. They're supposed to go on their own, PHP enabled web server (i.e. where you're developing your application). That server will then contact the server Solr is installed on through the URL given when you create the client. Solr bundles jetty, and being an Java application without any PHP support, has no idea what to do with PHP files.

Solr is not supposed to be exposed directly to the internet (at least not without knowing exactly what you're doing), and should only be reachable a location (either within a private network or firewalled away) from the server where your PHP code is running.